# Randomized Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, random, statistics, complexity-theory, amortized-analysis

I'm having trouble with a randomized problem. :)

A, a randomized algorithm, determines whether an input x is a prime number.

This algorithm works the following way:

> 1- If x is prime, then A outputs YES
>
> 2- If x is not prime, then A outputs NO with the probability 3/4.

At least how many times should we run A, if we want to have the algorithm  A output NO with the probability at least 1- (1/k)?

Note: One NO answer implies that a given input x is not prime.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

If a number `x` is not a prime, the probability to yield 'yes' in `n` repeats of the algorithm is `(1/4)^n = 4^(-n) = 2^(-2n)`.

So, if you want to achieve `1-(1/k)`, you are actually looking for *False Positive* with probability of at most `1/k`, and from the above we want:

```
2^(-2n) <= 1/k   //log_2 on both sides:
-2n <= log(1/k) = log(1)-log(k) = 0 - log(k)
2n >= log(k)
n >= log(k)/2
```

So you want to chose the smallest integer `n` possible such that `n >= log(k)/2`, to guarantee *True Negative* with probability of `1-1/k`.

(Note: All `log()` are with base 2).

**Example:**

If you want to be correct 99% of the time, you actually are looking for `1-1/k=0.99`, so `1/k=1/100` and `k=100`.

Now, according to the above formula, note that `log_2(100) ~= 6.64`, and thus the smallest `n` such that `n >= log_2(100)/2` is `n==4`.

Meaning, you need to repeat the algorithm 4 times to achieve 99%.

Let's check this is correct:

1. First check that the probability is indeed greater than 99%: `1-(1/4)^4 = 1-(1/256) ~= 0.996 >= 0.99`, so the probability is fine.
2. Check that for a smaller integer (n==3), we would have got worse than 99% correct answer: `1-(1/4)^3 = 1-1/64 ~=  0.984 < 0.99` - so we would have failed for `n==3`.

Comment: log k or (log k) / 2 times? i think your answer will be better if provide with an example. thanks.

Comment: @user3670084 `n >=[log(k)]/2`, added an example.

Comment: So we can say it's order of O(lg k)?